# Was I correct to use the word "establish" in my tweet? Should I have included adverbial "as"?

Tags: word-choice, adverbs, word-usage

English is not my native language, but I'm a willing pupil and in most cases I'm pretty confident in my knowledge, but sometimes I hesitate to use particular words. I wrote this [tweet recently](http://twitter.com/#!/Nemoden/status/72465335068008448):

> I amused. Person who cannot cope with "Cannot modify header information" error should not establish himself a web-developer.

I'm not sure if I made the sentence clear. Shouldn't I have used "establish **as** web-developer," or should I have not used the word "establish"?

Comment: You mean to say that someone like that should not "pose" as a web-developer?

Comment: Exactly. Yes... Or shouldn't call himself a "web-developer"

Comment: @Nemoden: well, I'm not a native speaker but it sounds a bit strange to me. However, I'll leave that for native speakers to answer ;)

Comment: It sounds strange to me either. That's why I've asked for help here :)

Comment: I think what the OP means is "start a business as a".

Comment: @Alain Pannetier, nope :)

Comment: @Nemodem, my mistake then ;)

Comment: @Alain Pannetier , well, if it is not understood what I meant, then probably mine :)

Comment: @Nemoden: Start with **I find that amusing. Anyone who can't cope...** and end with **shouldn't call himself a web developer**. And don't shorten **I have** to **I've** after **Shouldn't**.

Comment: ps - you're not a *hard-learner*, you're a *willing pupil*!

Comment: Thanks, @FumbleFingers for corrections :) BTW, I thought British people shorten everything more than Americans. Like "I've couldn't if he'd" etc. Aren't they? E.g. Americans don't usually shorten "would" word whilst British people does all the time. Is there some kind of rule when I can use shortened form and when it would be inappropriate (probably I should start a new question on this one)?

Comment: -1, too localised and a "Please proofread my document".

Comment: @Tim I did not asked for "proofread my document". I did not provide the quotation and placed link instead. Someone edited my question and added the actual quote from twitter. I don't know why it does bother you anyway. But what do you mean be "too localized"? I think "establish" word is widespread and means what it means and used where it used. I just asked if I use it properly. Thus, I consider your post and -1 as "trolling".

Comment: If that's a PHP-ism than maybe he's a perfectly good web programmer using better languages and can’t handle a crazy issue in a language he’d rather just avoid (the “real fix” is to use separate logic and template files).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I amused. Person who can not cope with
>   "Cannot modify header information"
>   error should not establish himself a
>   web-developer.

"I am amused. A person who can not cope with a 'cannot modify header information' error should not claim to be a web developer."

That would be a rough fix. An elegant solution would be:

"It's amusing that a person who can't handle a 'cannot modify header information' error claims to be a web developer."

But, in a larger sense, this kind of IT-level sniping is unhappy. If a colleague is having trouble, do not snipe - lend a helping hand.

Comment: Claim - this word is totally dropped out from my head and it fits perfectly... I mean this is exactly what I implied. So, can you tell is "establish" any good here anyway?

Comment: I would lend a helping hand only if this person would even try to google just a little bit. It's a really most common problem and the solution is described literary on **thousandths** of resources. I don't know... maybe I'm such a bad person...

Comment: +1 for elegant rephrasing *and* wise counsel. But I'd rather call it *undesirable* than *unhappy*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: The term "unhappy" has a particular meaning in formal linguistics.

Comment: @The Raven: That's as may be, but I think there's very little chance OP (or indeed most people reading this) will be aware of that. We're not on ling.SE yet.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Point taken. I'm in a bit of a quandry, here, because it's an extremely useful term in the exact sorts of discussions we have here. So part of me would like to see if I can popularize its use. If it fails to gain traction, I'll relent.

Comment: @The Raven: I actually thought a bit more about this one later. I am (vaguely) familiar with the specialised meaning, but to be honest not so much that I registered it on reading your comment (partly because mentally I was in the mode of interacting with OP). What we need is an EL&U 'glossary' that your usage could have 'hot-linked' to. Maybe we should suggest that in meta?

Comment: Great idea - I'll propose in meta and suggest some links.

Comment: Proposed at meta: http://is.gd/8Hezac

Answer (score 4):

try:

> I'm amused. A person who can't cope
>   with a "Cannot modify header
>   information" error **has no business
>   calling** himself a web-developer.

or

> I'm amused. A person who can't cope
>   with a "Cannot modify header
>   information" error **shouldn't pass
>   himself** of as a web-developer.

Comment: Typo: s/of/off/g

Answer (score 3):

I don't think 'establish' is apt in that context. An alternative could be "consider" as in ...should not **consider** himself...

Comment: Consider would fit here, but it seems to be a little "soft". I want to say that person should not even dare to think he is a web-developer. "Consider" assumes he can think of it, right? :)